# Signature extraction from PDF using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, digital-signature

Let's say I have a digitally signed PDF document (with filled in form). I need to find a way to validate that PDF file using PHP.

I know that I have to use function `openssl_verify($data, $signature, $pub_key_id)` .
I need 3 parameters (I have public certificate).

How do I extract signed data and signature itself from the PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to parse the PDF - in theory, you can write your own parsing functions. However, you would save a lot of time by using something ready-made.

What about [Apache's PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)? You could execute it as any other shell script, or use some [PHP/Java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/).

If you decide to go manual way, see [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) for a way of implementing your parser - you should be able to just ignore any complex parts and fish out the signature by looking for startxref.

There are also proprietary solutions like [VersyPDF.PHP](http://www.sybrex.com/products/development/versypdf/versypdf_php/) but those may be a bit of an overkill for your job (but on the plus side you may get away with using the evaluation version as you do not care about watermarked output).

Answer (score 0):

To extract data and signature, you can use numbers in /ByteRange field of PDF. It has 4 numbers as /ByteRange[a b c d]. The signature is from b(th) byte to c(th) byte and remaining is data. 
In PHP, you can use stream_get_contents() function to get content by stream.